# Change default date format in input mask: Is it possible?

Tags: 8, datetime

I adapted the default date formats to the German needs, and I created a new date format for output. This works fine.

For the input, the *Y-m-d* format persists. How do I change this?
I've created a content type: "events".
I defined a field type of DATE:

[image: Field type of date]

In the manage form display I've set its witget to "Date and Time. There's no wheel to define dmY or other.

[image: Widget on date field]

The result in input mask:

[image: input mask]

The only thing that works at the moment, is the widget switching to "date as a list" to get german notation.

Comment: I've updated the answer several hours ago, did you have chance to check if that was working out for you ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the machine name of your content type is "test".

Please navigate to:
**admin/structure/types/manage/*test*/form-display**

You should see the following form (with different fields, of course).[image]

In my example, the name of the field is simply "date" .
You can change the widget to Select list and then you will see the cog wheel on the right side of the row.

After clicking on it, you shall be able to choose your preferred Date Format.
[image]

Hopefully that helps.

Update 1: Regarding Update
In my default Drupal installation when I try to add date-based fields, I do have the following 2 options:

- Date
- Timestamp

Option Date
I have suboptions, "Date only" or "Date and time"[image]

- If I choose "Date and time" -> I am able to see the select widget as
  option.
- If I choose "Date only" -> I am able to see the select widget
  as option.

Timestamp
I am able to see only Datetime timestamp
[image]

As a last thing:
Screenshot, showing the different type of fields in Manage form Display:
[image]

**Update 2:**
It seems the following article has it explained how to do the exact thing you are looking for:
https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/making-drupal-8-datetime-widgets-use-human-formats

Comment: But what about the "Date and Time"? I believe there is no possibility to change its format. It's a pity, because the embedded calendar works fine as it is.

Comment: I am adding a comment, just to update the answer, based on this additional question.

Comment: Please mark the question as accepted if you think It answers your question in detail.

Comment: I've added some images, hope, that's now more understandable. 
I apologize for any difficulties at my beginning in this forum.
Frank

Comment: Hi Frank,
This makes it more understandable for me, thank you.
They say a picture counts a thousand words, hehe.
I understand that for the datepicker widget you would like to change the format.
I am not aware what would be the exact code to do that, but for now I am looking at the documentation in core\lib\Drupal\Core\Datetime\Element\Datetime.php #date_date_format, apparently there are some HTML 5 restrictions.  I will investigate later more, because this is an interesting issue. Regards

Comment: I think I have found an answer, which is code based, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Hi Oleg, that may be the right answer. But currently I'm not able to use it. How to place a hook and where: I Don't know: So much to learning to create a simple Drupal site ;-)

Comment: After updating to version 8.4.4, this issue has been fixed in my real-time system.
In a local reinstallation of 8.4.4 I still have the problem (Acquia dev desktop).
However, I do not see any difference to my live installation.
A server-based problem?
What has happened there?

Comment: Unfortunately the solution provided in "update 2" doesn't work anymore on D8.9.1... All the work needs to be redoed